# C as back-end of a website service

Tags: php, html, c, web-services, backend

I know nothing about web development but I am trying to figure out how to use a C program that i created to communicate with a website made in HTML. I've done a bit of research and it seems i can use PHP to call the C program with an exec command which will create a new process. From my understanding PHP makes HTML dynamic so what i'm trying to do is pass information from C to the PHP part that modifies my HTML code to display up to date information. Is there any other way to communicate information besides the exec command?

Comment: If you're doing this from C, what made your bring PHP into the picture? Consider a webkit like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (the name is somewhat self-explanatory). I apologize in advance if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit too much, but if you want to go further into web development, you should take a look at [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/).

Comment: @WhozCraig, i am not sure how to display information from the C program to the HTML dynamically without PHP so thats why i mentioned it.

Comment: I'm rather confused as to what your goal is. Hazarding a guess, you want to go to have a webpage which is built by a C program, is this even close? You don't need PHP anywhere in the picture, however, it does include a lot of useful parsing which you'll have to do yourself in C. The answer regarding the CGI protocol would be a good place to start.

Comment: standard unix pipes could be the way to go, if you want your C program to continuously run in the background. (that is, if it should not be started new for each request)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin, how do i do that? could you explain a little more or point me to some info? thanks

Comment: sure, here is some information on daemons in linux: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html so write yourself a daemon and use for example a fifo (http://pronix.linuxdelta.de/C/Linuxprogrammierung/Linuxsystemprogrammieren_C_Kurs_Kapitel5b.shtml) for the interprocess communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into CGI? I understand that's what is used to run payment systems and so on. I have no experience myself but that should get you started.

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html